# How to use SD card as adoptable on LG K8

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, adoptable-storage

Lately I've bought LG K8 but it doesn't have much memory, so after installing few apps and updating stock apps there was about 1.5 GB remaining. Also I have an 16 GB SD card and I found that on android 6.0 SD could be used as adoptable storage so it becomes internal. I have two questions. 
First: if I do that will I have more space for installing apps or I could use it just for media?
Second: how to make SD card become adoptable I searched for that option everywhere but couldn't find it, is it possible that I can't do that even I have android 6.0?

Comment: LG did not implement adoptable storage.

Comment: @acejavelin 
So, it's not possible even through the ADB?

Comment: Correct, the app calls for immersive mode, you can't just flip a switch and toggle it on and off. In some custom ROMs, they can force full screen but it's done with trickery by turning off the navigation and notification bars off.

Comment: @acejavelin What are talking about, I didn't asked anything about immersive mode..?

Comment: lol... I'm sorry, somehow I replied to the wrong post.... Yes, I believe it can be implemented by adb, if it works for the G4 it should work for other LG models as well so it seems LG just left it out of the GUI not completely dropped it, a simple google search can find the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone wondering how to enable adoptable storage, here is how to [CLICK](https://www.xda-developers.com/enable-adoptable-storage-for-galaxy-s7-and-s7-edge/)

It says 'for galaxy s7 and s7 edge' but it works for every android 6+ phone